# How can I stop a series from drawing at a certain value in Google Line Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Is there any option to stop a series from drawing at a certain value in Google Line Chart? Here is what I am getting now:

[image]

I want the red series to stop a series from drawing further if rest are 0. Is this possible?

There are two obvious questions
**1. How I will determine whether rest of the values are 0 and**
**2. What if not all values after 240 are 0**

And this is what I need:
[image]

But in my case, it is obvious. At one point I will always receive the rest for this series as 0.

Comment: Can you set these 0 values to null or undefined instead?  If so, that would be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as posted in the comment, convert the zero values to `null`,
this will prevent a line from being drawn.

to determine the last values are zero,
loop backwards from the end of the rows,
before drawing the chart.

once you find a value not equal to zero,
break out of the loop.

```
// convert last zero values to null
for (var i = data.getNumberOfRows() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (data.getValue(i, 1) === 0) {
    data.setValue(i, 1, null);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('chart');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['X', 'Y'],
    [new Date(2019, 3, 1), 113],
    [new Date(2019, 4, 1), 145],
    [new Date(2019, 5, 1), 165],
    [new Date(2019, 6, 1), 187],
    [new Date(2019, 7, 1), 214],
    [new Date(2019, 8, 1), 240],
    [new Date(2019, 9, 1), 0],
    [new Date(2019, 10, 1), 0],
    [new Date(2019, 11, 1), 0]
  ]);

  // convert last zero values to null
  for (var i = data.getNumberOfRows() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (data.getValue(i, 1) === 0) {
      data.setValue(i, 1, null);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  // get chart date range
  var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);

  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: dateRange.min,
        max: dateRange.max
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```